# MahApps slider margin

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I am trying to make simple video Player with MahApps. I have a little problem with layout of flyout. I want to put slider into flyout and make its width equal to flyout width.

```
<Controls:FlyoutsControl>
    <Controls:Flyout Padding="0" Name="mediaStatus" Height="auto" CloseButtonVisibility="Collapsed" IsOpen="False" Position="Bottom">
            <Slider Padding="0" Margin="0" Style="{DynamicResource FlatSlider}"></Slider>
    </Controls:Flyout>
</Controls:FlyoutsControl>
```

With this code I'm getting something like this:

[screenshot](http://prntscr.com/goaafs)

What can I do to delete this margin on the left of the slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must also set `TitleVisibility="Collapsed"`. The title/header is still visible on the left side (with some margin which produces this black space).